# ListView has been removed from ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I have just installed the project and ran it on my device but It show me the error "ListView has been removed from ReactNative". I do not understand why it is happening because I did not use List View in project. Here is screen shot.

[image]

I think this error comes from node_modules library. Which use List View.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo_app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.1",
    "react-native-exception-handler": "^2.10.2",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-native-ui-kitten": "^3.1.2",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SplashScreen from "./src/components/main/SplashScreen";
import {
  BackHandler,
} from "react-native";
import { Root } from 'native-base';

import { Scene, Router, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';


export default class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => Actions.pop());
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Root>
        <Router>
          <Scene key="root">
            <Scene initial key="splash" component={SplashScreen} hideNavBar />

          </Scene>
        </Router>
      </Root>
    );
  }

}
```

**SplashScreen.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  ImageBackground,
  AsyncStorage,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from "react-native";



export default class SplashScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    headerVisible: false
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    this.state = {
      result: null
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      demo
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {},
  image: {
    height: 130,
    width: 240
  },
  overlay1: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"
  },
  linearGradient: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes from native-base

[reference](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/blob/master/src/basic/Content.js#L5)

When it will be fixed, that's another question to native-base ;)